# PHP how do i cut substring after last slash?

Tags: php, regex, string

Hi i want to know how can i get substring from string after last slash?
In short i want to get the file name from path.

for example i got string like this:
`test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/6.png`
and i want to get `6.png` how can i do that ?
I got dir only and the file name can be all format, it can be also something else then file

Or `test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/aaaaa` and want to get `aaaaa`

Regex maybe? Or maybe you know some nice functions which will do it for me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to other replies, there's actually a function in PHP to do this: `basename`. Example:

```
$string = 'test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/6.png';
$base = basename($string); // $base == '6.png';

$string = 'test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/aaaaa';
$base = basename($string); // $base == 'aaaaa'

$string = '6.png';
$base = basename($string); // $base == '6.png'
```

Full details here: http://php.net/basename

Comment: and what in case my string look like: `6.png` ? will it return exception ??

Comment: `basename('6.png') === '6.png'` (ie, it'll just return the string)

Comment: I did not know this! Thank you very much. I will be using this function for now on when dealing with this specific criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Do like this..

```
$yourstring = 'test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/6.png';
$val = array_pop(explode('/',$yourstring)); // 6.png
```

Comment: and what in case my string look like: `6.png` ? will it return exception ? or still explode will set an one element array ?

Comment: @Vardius Any particular reason that prevents you from testing that yourself ? …

Answer (score 1):

You can try [explode](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [array_pop](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) functions to work this out:

```
$str = 'test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/aaaaa.png';
$str = explode('/', $str);
$filename = array_pop($str);

echo $filename; //Output will be aaaaa.png
```

Answer (score 1):

...Or you can use the following regex:
`[^\/]*$`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this, you can use `substr()` to get a portion of the string, and `strrpos()` to specify which portion:

```
$full_path = "test-e2e4/test-e2e4/test-e2e4/6.png"
$file      = substr( $full_path, strrpos( $full_path, "/" ) + 1 );
```

`substr()` returns a portion of the string, `strrpos()` tells it to start from the position of the last slash in the string, and the +1 excludes the slash from the return value.